# Getting two vagrant VMs to communicate

Tags: vagrant

I've looked around a lot for a solution to what seems to be a simple problem, and have not come up with an answer.

I have a Vagrantfile which defines two VMs:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define :box1 do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
    config.vm.hostname = "box1"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.21"
    config.vm.provision :hosts
  end

  config.vm.define :box2 do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
    config.vm.hostname = "box2"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.22"
    config.vm.provision :hosts
  end
end
```

So, my understanding of this is that I'm giving each box its own IP address, and then running the `hosts` provisioner (provided by the [`vagrant-hosts` plugin](https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-hosts)). From the vagrant-hosts docs, this should be all I need to do.

However:

```
$ vagrant ssh box1 -c 'ping 192.128.0.22'
PING 192.168.0.22 (192.168.0.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.21 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.22 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5031ms
pipe 3
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make two VMs communicate with each other. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

By default Vagrant uses NAT networking for the guest VM instances.

You will need to alter the VM configuration to change it to Bridged networking (the easiest) or create a virtual network switch to allow inter-VM communication (or something along those lines) for whatever hypervisor provider you are using. This varies by provider and does not appear to be directly supported by Vagrant.

http://friendsofvagrant.github.io/v1/docs/bridged_networking.html

In fact it appears that the official Vagrant documentation doesn't seem to indicate support for Bridged networking but instead allows you to configure public networks. Those may be more than you need/want but for what it's worth:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html